# Azure B2C Custom Policy Password Reset Hide Cancel Button

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

On my custom policy for password reset I want to hide the cancel button highlighted below.  I really don't want to do custom html or css. Are there any other options to hiding the button in a custom policy?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lv57.jpg)

I've tried the MetaData route to specify a Key with a value of showCancelButton to false but I believe that only applies to the initial login page.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the metadata key to the TRUSTFRAMEWORKBASE.XML file. You may also want to include your Forgot Password Technical Profile to the question.